# Insert a través de modal (bootstrap) no finaliza submit(mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Lo dicho, tengo el modal y se me abre correctamente pero cuando le doy a guardar, se queda sin hacer nada y parece que no coge el PHP.

Tanto el PHP como el código HTML están en el mismo fichero.

```
<?php

require "../db/configdb.php";

if (isset($_POST['cod_mh']))
{
    echo "1";
    try 
    {
        echo $_POST['cod_mh'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mh(codigo_mh) VALUES ('".$_POST['cod_mh']."');";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }else{

        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $error) 
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
    $connextion->close();
}
?>
```

Por otro lado, tengo el modal...

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#MHModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-md"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i>Insertar</a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="MHModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Insertar MH</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cod_mh" class="control-label">Código MH</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod_mh">
                        </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

He incluido también el botón que abre el popup.

Le estoy dando muchísimas vueltas todo el rato para ver porque no me coge el PHP y creo que es porque no lo está cogiendo bien debido a que el php no se carga en el modal. Van por ahí los tiros?

La función de PHP me ha funcionado anteriormente con otro codigo lo que pasa que estoy intentando hacerlo con bootstrap.

Comment: Buenas, parece que no tienes indicado en el form el fichero php a ejecutar cuando hagas el submit. Sin embargo me desconcierta que digas que te ha funcionado sin el modal.

Comment: El codigo php está en el mismo fichero. Entonces no debo apuntar a ningún fichero y...debería funcionar, no?

Comment: Creo que no tienes muy claro el funcionamiento de la web. Un fichero php se puede usar para generar un fichero html con el que el usuario interactúe, pero también para recoger las peticiones POST del usuario (submits en formularios). En definitiva, para que el submit se lleve a cabo, necesitas indicar en el form el action="fichero.php". Y en este fichero procesar la petición del formulario, que supongo que guardará algo en base de datos.

Comment: Para apuntar al mismo fichero debido a que el código PHP y HTML está en el mismo fichero es necesario usar en el "action" lo siguiente: <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

Comment: Solucionado con...<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">